# can i install perl module in my hosting provider machine

Tags: perl

My hosting service provider has not installed **HTML::Template** perl module, and he is not ready to install it giving some security concerns.

Is there any way, i can install it in my root directory or any other place and can use it.

If yes then how and how can i use it?

is there any other option except change the host provider?

Please provide your comments.

Thanks, Devesh

Comment: It may or may not be possible to install the library locally, but if your service provider doesn't want to install it due to security concerns, aren't you likely to run afoul of your terms of service?

Comment: The module is nothing but Perl code, so there's no security threat posed by the module that isn't implicit in the ability to upload your webapp to begin with (and equally, if you can upload a script, then by definition you can install a pure-perl module along with it).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

First you need to check with your SP that you can install modules in your local directory. If yes then you need to check whether you have basic tools to build & install. [This post helps](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=128077)

If basic build tools aren't installed, then it will be difficult but not impossible.